# Select2 Hide Popup label/tooltip on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using select2 with remotely populated data.  Part of the selected text that shows in the input has a link in it.   For this field, I notice the link shows in the label when I hover over it.

Can I just disable this tooltip feature altogether so it looks better?

[image]